# PHP CSV - indeterminate rows to columns

Tags: php

I have a CSV file of clients with feature names and a (Metadata) json string that defines that feature.  Each client can have anywhere between 10 to 15 features, and there's no way to be sure which client has what.

Visually in this format:

| Client | Feature | Metadata |
| --- | --- | --- |
| client1 | featureName1 | jsonstring |
| client1 | featureName2 | jsonstring |
| client1 | featureName3 | jsonstring |
| client2 | featureName1 | jsonstring |
| client2 | featureName2 | jsonstring |
| client2 | featureName3 | jsonstring |

With this data, I need to create a readable format of the json for stakeholders to understand how the features are being used by our clients. Manually, I created a spreadsheet with each client on a single row with the metadata in columns. This isn't maintainable, considering it took me a solid weekend to do, and the number of clients is rising.

Now I'm looping through the CSV file to create columns for each client from the metadata; but I don't know each feature that a client will have, so I can't dynamically build a table with matching header row.  Here's what I've started building, and you can see in the logic that if a feature doesn't exist then the data won't match the header:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Client</td>
            <td>adminNotifications</td>
            <td>indexerJobSync - default</td>
            <td>indexerJobSync - defined</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><?php
            $file = fopen("query.csv", "r");
            fgetcsv($file); //skip first row
            while (!feof($file)) {
                $data = fgetcsv($file, null, ';');
                $meta = json_decode($data[3], TRUE);
                if ($data[0] === 'BillyBobsCrabShack') {
                    if ($data[1] === 'adminNotifications') echo "<td>" . $meta['email'] . "</td>";
                    if ($data[1] === 'indexerJobSync') echo "<td>" . $meta['defaultIndexer'] . "</td><td>" . $meta['definedIndexer'] . "</td>";
                }
            }
            fclose($file);
            ?></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Your issue is that by the time you know you need to change the table headers you've already output them to the browser. Build the full data structure _first_, _then_ render it out to the page. The general rule of thumb is "logic first, display second" because trying to do both at the same time is usually needlessly complex.

Comment: @Sammitch, suggestions on how to do that, since I don't know which features exist for each client?

Edit: To add to the problem; each feature doesn't have a set number of key/value pairs, so I can't know ahead of time the number of columns to create.

Comment: You _do_ know, because they're in your data. Do one loop that builds out an array that contains all of that information, and then a second, separate loop that uses that information to construct the table.

Comment: OK, that's a good point.  Create an initial array of data, and then act on it for the display.  Thanks, going to play with this and come back with results.

Comment: @Sammitch, I've got it now.  If you want some credit, add an answer and I'll accept it.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing logic to create an array that I can work with first, and display second.  In my situation, the number of features is finite but they're not enabled across all clients, so I created an array of features with clients assigned to them.

```
$file = fopen("query.csv", "r");
  fgetcsv($file); //skip first row
  $newdata = [];
  while (!feof($file)) {
    $data = fgetcsv($file, null, ';');
    $newdata[$data[1]][$data[0]] = $data[3];
  }
  fclose($file);
```

And this creates an array such as:

```
Array
(
    [feature1] => Array
        (
            [client1] => jsonstring
            [client2] => jsonstring
            [client3] => jsonstring
        )

    [feature2] => Array
        (
            [client4] => jsonstring
            [client5] => jsonstring
            [client6] => jsonstring
        )
)
```

From there, I just write the array keys into my display, or however I need to handle it:

```
<?= isset($newdata['fileCategory']['client1']) ? "TRUE":"FALSE" ?>
```